# How to quick render simple scenes in low res in Blender?

Tags: render, blender

I have started using blender to make simple 3d animations, but my laptop will heat up too fast when rendering, and also it takes too much time to render even simple scenes.

I just want to output easily and fast a low res image of the scene, like the ones on the 3D View, but I didn't find any easy nor fast way to do that.

Preferably I will be using cycles.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Making renders faster is almost a university degree by itself. [Here is a forty seven minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gSyEpt4-60) with some tips.

The simplest step with any render engine is to reduce the resolution. In the [render dimensions panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/render/output/settings.html) set the percentage to 50% or 25%.

Using 2.79 you can do [opengl renders](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/opengl.html), which is what you see in the viewport. You can enable the display of [only render objects](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/properties/panels.html) to hide all the viewport overlays.

For cycles set the [samples](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/render/cycles/render_settings/sampling.html) low and use the [denoising options](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/render/layers/denoising.html). The daily builds, which will be 2.81 when released also includes the new denoise composite node that uses [Intel's OpenImageDenoise](https://openimagedenoise.github.io) for better [results](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbpMNr0PR7M).

If you really want to speed up render times, use blender 2.80 and the [EVEE render engine](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/introduction.html), it is almost realtime and offers [amazing results](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=evee+showcase). With 2.80 almost all of the material nodes from cycles will produce the same result in evee and for 2.81 this has been improved even more.